# How can i check end of line for Range?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to export a json file from excel, the json file basically contains a single object with a lot of keys and values. the row D would be the key and the offset of it would be the value. i would like to add comma at each of the end line if the keys but i have no idea how to stop adding commas at the end of the keys. i am trying to do checking on the last item of the range, but apparently i failed to match the condition, so every line is showing commas. I really appreciate if anyone could lend me a helping hand. here's my code:

```
Dim encodedData As String
Dim data As String

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim f As Object
Set f = fso.CreateTextFile(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\exports\zh-CN.json", True, True)

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Sheets(1).Range("D2"), Sheets(1).Range("D2").End(xlDown)) 'use this for dynamic range

f.Write "{" + Chr(10)
For Each cell In rng
    f.Write Chr(34) + cell.Value + Chr(34) + ": " + Chr(34) + cell.Offset(0, 5).Value + Chr(34)

    If Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlDown).Row <> cell.Row Then
        f.Write "," + Chr(10)
    Else
        f.Write Chr(10)
    End If

Next

f.Write "}" + Chr(10)
f.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out I have to find the number of the rows, and compare it with the current row the cell is moving down into, here's the complete solution:

```
Dim currentRow As String
Dim lastRow As String

Dim myWorksheet As Object
Set myWorksheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
myWorksheet.UsedRange

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim f As Object
Set f = fso.CreateTextFile(Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\exports\zh-CN.json", True, True)

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range(Sheets(1).Range("D2"), Sheets(1).Range("D2").End(xlDown)) 'use this for dynamic range

f.Write "{" + Chr(10)
For Each cell In rng
    f.Write Chr(34) + cell.Value + Chr(34) + ": " + Chr(34) + cell.Offset(0, 5).Value + Chr(34)

    currentRow = cell.Row
    lastRow = myWorksheet.UsedRange.Row + myWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

    If currentRow <> lastRow Then
        f.Write "," + Chr(10)
    Else
        f.Write Chr(10)
    End If

Next

f.Write "}" + Chr(10)
f.Close
```